# EXT4 Ideal Size?

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I have 1TB HDD and I will use ubuntu and won't use dual boot with windows, any tips about partitions' size and how many partitions, can I have just 2 partitions?

The second question is about swap partition, do I have to make a separate partition for swap specially when I can use a file as a swap, is there any performance gain?

Comment: None, there are no rules for partition size, create as many as you like. SWAP is used for giving you extra "RAM" aka. virtual memory in the scenario you run out of real RAM, there are no performance gains from this,  as it uses the hard drive for this and it's slower than actual RAM. You may also want SWAP if you plan to use Hibernation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the swap partition at least 4 GB, and it is better than a swap file as the file may become fragmented under some conditions, especially while it is being made. It also helps hibernation.

Therefore, a swap partition is better if you are not constrained with partition layout.

You can then use the rest of the disk as a `/` partition, or make another set to mount in `/home` so you can keep your home partition separate from any other files. However, 2 partitions (swap and `/`) are good, and the swap can be around 4GB, and the other partition can fill the rest of the disk.

Comment: my RAM is 8 GB, is there a relation between it and the swap partition; can the swap partition be larger or smaller?

Comment: 16GB is probably overkill, 4GB is fine unless you are planning to run heavy servers (like Minecraft(r)) or do a lot of video editing.